# How to convert import/export to es5 without .require() methods using GULP?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I want to create GULP task manager for my project and I need to convert javascripts from ecmascript6 to ecmascript5. So I try to use babel:

```
gulp.task('babel', function() {
return gulp.src(path.watch.js)
    .pipe(babel({
        presets: ['es2015'],
        plugins: ['transform-object-rest-spread']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.jsDist)); });
```

, where path.watch.js is path string './src/js/**/*.js', path.jsDist is destination folder ('./dist/js/').
My JS files consists import/export and as result after convertation I'll get javascript with all exported modules and .require() methods. But it is unsuitable script for most of browsers. I need to have one prettified common JS bundle in destination folder (for example APP.JS, using gulp-concat module) and I have no idea how to do this correctly.